# Windows keeps creating new network connections

Tags: windows, networking, internet-connection, network-adapter

I am on a company network, connected through cable and Wifi, and new network connections keep popping up from time to time.

Excess network connections:

[image]

I can delete them manually, but they keep reappearing. I tried uninstalling the base network connection (Ethernet - Killer 2200) driver and reinstalling it, but to no avail.

How can I prevent these connections from appearing and why do they appear in the first place?

System info:

- Windows 10
- Killer E2200 Gigabit Ethernet controller
- MSI GP 2QE Leopard Pro laptop (intel i7)

Answer (score 0):

The Tap-Win32 Adapter is a virtual network interface needed on your PC to allow the VPN connection to the Talk2M server. This adapter is added on your PC during the eCatcher installation process.

So some program like a VM or VPN is trying to create the adapter.